# React Table data logic construction

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table, datatables, material-ui

I want to ask if there is easier way to display data.
Here is my dummy data:

```
const data = [
  {
    business: false,
    utilization: {
      ActiveParticipantsPercent: 55.55,
      SeparatedVestedParticipants: 0,
      ParticipantsWithBenefitAccount: 8,
      AverageActiveParticipants: 5,
      TotalContributions: 23890
    },
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    business: true,
    utilization: {
      ActiveParticipantsPercent: 82.4,
      SeparatedVestedParticipants: 1.94,
      ParticipantsWithBenefitAccount: 95393,
      AverageActiveParticipants: 0.01,
      TotalContributions: 257094.79
    },
    year: 2018
  }
];
```

I want to display the data in 2 columns - one is 2018 with false business value and the other is 2018 with true business value.
For each of them I want to display data of the utilization fields.

I prepared sandbox to see how I did it but I think there might be easier way to do it and to save resources: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-worker-ixf6r?file=/src/App.js

Any suggestions or should I keep it in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate between the `utilization` object (the rows) and inside of a row, iterate between the data array (the cells) instead of hard coding each `TableRow` and then iterating in it

Example:

```
// basically the number of rows based on utilization properties plus the header (+1)
let rowCount = Object.keys(data[0].utilization).length + 1;

<TableContainer component={Paper}>
  <Table size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
    <TableBody>
      {[...Array(rowCount)].map((_, i) => {
        let current_utilization_key =
          i === 0 ? "Field" : Object.keys(data[0].utilization)[i - 1];

        return (
          <TableRow key={i}>
            <TableCell>{current_utilization_key}</TableCell>
            {data.map((el, j) => {
              let cell_content = "";

              // just some condition statements to determine if cell is to be a header or if business evaluates to true
              if (i === 0) {
                if (el.business === true) {
                  cell_content = "Business for " + el.year;
                } else {
                  cell_content = el.year;
                }
              } else {
                cell_content = el.utilization[current_utilization_key];
              }

              return <TableCell key={j}>{cell_content}</TableCell>;
            })}
          </TableRow>
        );
      })}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

[image: Edit React MUI Table By Rows]

Comment: Is there to compare elements from the same row which is bigger? For example from the Sandbox: ActiveParticipantsPercent field which of 2 is bigger?

Comment: you mean like a sorting functionality? that is best done on the data source. e.g., on the database query. if done on the client-side, that is a separate logic - you can leverage [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and write your custom comparison function. or `map` if you are into immutability